# Why my setTimeout function shows the console part only once after a time span of 10 seconds but after that it prints the console part in 1seconds

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('distance');
        rootRef.on('value',snap =>{
            console.log("Usage value",snap.val());
            let prevData=this.state.percentage;
            this.consumptionHandler(prevData, snap.val())
            this.watermeterHandler(snap.val());
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log('hi');
            },10000)

        })
```

I am trying to make a web application using react. It uses firebase as a database.I am working on a realtime firebase database. I was wondering that if i use the setTimeout function inside the .on() I thought that 'hi' will be printed after every 10 seconds , but unlikely only for the first time 'hi' appeared after 10 seconds and after that 'hi' in just one second.My functions i.e consumptionHandler and watermeterHandler are working fine, i only have issues with the setTimeout function.

Does the settimeout function works only once?

Please provide a solution such that 'hi' appears in the console only after every one seconds.

Let me know if more information required.

See if this console image is of some help
[image: console image]

In the image the usage value is the value i am getting from my firebase.As a new beginner i don't know much about web development but i think that the .on() method is running recursively but why for each recursion setTimeout is not working properly as the first 'hi' appears after 10 second but it is not same for other 'hi' as shown in the image.

As guided i wrote a similar simple code of what i want to achieve but in this code the setTimeout out works properly.

```
const recursiveHandler=(i)=>{
  if(i ===10){
    return
  }
  setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(i);
      i++;
      recursiveHandler(i)
  }, 10000)

}

recursiveHandler(1);
```

Comment: Yes, `setTimeout` callback function is called only once upon timeout. Is this code running somewhere and getting invoked multiple times, i.e. setting more than one timeout? It may help to actually provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: the above code is used inside componentDidMount function

Comment: Did the component mount and two (or more) `value` events occurred, seconds apart? With the timeout doing the same thing for each event how would/could you tell the difference?

Comment: `rootRef.on` is just simply an event handler that calls the specified callback when the specified event occurs.  No recursion. I'm sure if you `console.log('hi', snap.val());` (***note:** you may need to save the `snap.val()` to a local variable in callback scope*) in the `setTimeout` callback you'll see it pairs with exactly one "Usage value XXX.XXX" log from about 10 seconds prior. It's a bit nonsensical, but IMO looks to be functioning as coded. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Actually i am trying to make a water meter for which i wanted to update the data after 24 hours , in order to do so i was just checking if i could achieve it by setTimeout method.But i figured out it does not works. Can you please suggest any solution.

Comment: Do you write tests for code you create? Lots of answers to be found there. Is this code that'll be running 24 hours/day, in a browser? Are you simply wanting to "refresh" a page, or the data it's rendering, at least once every 24 hours?

Comment: I have a state which has a consumption field, and for the whole day i want to update my water consumption value for the day and as soon as next day arrives the consumption value must become 0 and the same process will begin in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

could be you need to use rootRef.once instead of rootRef.on then setInterval instead of setTimeout. I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve